# Why does this error google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError in firebase_admin lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase-admin

I followed a detailed youtube video tutorial and wrote the code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/firebase/dsffd-a55b6-firebase-adminsdk-o3dda-42a1614ac9.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"databaseURL": "https://dsffd-a55b6-default-rtdb.europe-           west1.firebasedatabase.app/"})
ref = db.reference("/")
                         
ref.get()
```

This is the error that appears:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token 
must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. 
Check your iat and exp values in the 
JWT claim.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid 
JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable 
timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.'})
```

Comment: Did you manage to find out a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution

Comment: The time on your device must be appropriate for the time zone. Go to the time settings and make it automatic, and the problem will be solved

Comment: Yes, that was the issue with me as well.